# Error Getting Google Spreadsheet as JSON

Tags: json, google-sheets

I am trying to get a googlespreadsheet data as json using

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1KI1hps-RpAJZV8AkB6MpxO8V_le--111111111/od6/public/values?alt=json
```

but I get error message saying:
"We're sorry. This document is not published."

The link to spreadsheet itself is working fine and anyone can access (indicating the sharing has no problem)

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/111111-RpAJZV8AkB6MpxO8V_le--111111/edit#gid=0
```

Appreciate if anyone can tell me what is the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two api endpoints aren't the same. A published spreadsheet isn't the same as one that can be edited by anyone.

Not sure why it needs to be published to export it as json, but here are the instructions:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en

Comment: Works can you post the url in the question. I'm on a phone.

Comment: just worked it out, I published it before using web deploy from script editor it seems you have to also go to the spreadsheet and file menu and publish to web

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.